# Is it possible to persist Redux state on browser refresh without using local storage or a module?

Tags: redux, redux-saga, redux-router

I am looking at an application that I need to extend and some routes do not lose the state when I refresh the browser while others do, I looked for local storage and modules such us redux-persist but none of that has been implemented, comparing the code in routes and sagas does not show any obvious difference between the routes that work (keep the state) and the ones that don't.

Is there any other way to persist the state?

Comment: I finally resolved this issue importing global sagas into the "page component" sagas

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to a route and pass `state` using `react-router`, depending on what browser you use, that `state` object will be persisted through page refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

You could persist the JSON representation of your state into a cookie. This is something that I have seen being done before.

Answer (score 0):

You could URL Base64 Encode the state and put it in the URL as a parameter.

I am sure there is an NPM package to look for, here is an example using:
https://www.browserling.com/tools/json-to-base64

{ user: user1 }
becomes eyB1c2VyOiB1c2VyMSB9

You could then set this in the browser URL like url.com/?context=eyB1c2VyOiB1c2VyMSB9

This should persist through a refresh and could be set back into the state of the component from the ComponentDidMount lifecycle